# How to prevent calling all 'onEvent' methods in class hierarchy

Tags: android, greenrobot-eventbus

I am struggling with preventing call all methods in class hierarchy chain.
Lets say i have a **base class**:

```
class BaseModel 

{ /* Some basic fields goes here */ }

class ModelCompany extends BaseModel

{ /* Fields goes here */ }
```

Then I want to post two different events:

```
BaseModel oneEvent = new BaseModel();

ModelCompany otherEvent = new ModelCompany();

EventBus.getDefault().post(oneEvent);

EventBus.getDefault().post(otherEvent);
```

---

**Somewhere in the activity**:

```
onEvent(BaseModel ev1){}

onEvent(ModelCompany ev2){}
```

---

The thing is that both onEvent method will be executed in this case. How to prevent it and post message to exact method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in EventBus 3 with [EventBusBuilder.eventInheritance()](http://greenrobot.org/files/eventbus/javadoc/3.0/org/greenrobot/eventbus/EventBusBuilder.html#eventInheritance-boolean-)